# Connect to rsync with custom port and NO SSH

Tags: linux, port, rsync

using an rsync server on a QNAP NAS which is configured to port 50011, I try to connect from an Ubuntu Server.

So far I have not found a way to change default port 873 to a custom one for connection, except when using the `-e 'ssh -p50011'` option. Unfortunately QNAP does not understand SSH for rsync.

The web has plenty of how-to's about using a custom port with SSH. Is there a way WITHOUT USING SSH?

thanks & regards
David

Answer (score 1):

Found it:
use the `--port=50011` directive.

brgds
David

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `rsync -rav --delete --port=xxxx "$SSH_USERNAME"@"$SSH_HOST":./  /home/"$SSH_USERNAME"/src` results in "Connection to host x.x.x.x port 22: connection refused"

Answer (score 0):

Besides `--port` one should be able to use port inside the address when specifying rsync:// prefix: `rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/SRC` :

```
> rsync --list-only rsync://127.0.0.1:9010/test1/ | grep test2
-rw-r--r--              0 2021/05/19 12:40:25 test2
```